# line break not working in ion-item

Tags: angular, ionic2

I stuck into this simple problem. Not finding any solution.

Following is not working:

```
<div text-wrap ion-item no-lines>
            "No result found. <br/> Please enter your search criteria."
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried with \n or br tag

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and had to put a div within the ion-item:

```
<ion-item>
  <div>
    first line
    <br/>
    second line
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

You can also try this:

```
white-space: pre-line !important;
```